# How to fix image not showing up in other computer?

Tags: wordpress, image, elementor

Need problem with image not showing up on the client side.
I make the website on wordpress with Elementor.
The images not showing up on the client side but its shows normally on me & other computer I tested.

Here is the video thats shows up on client computer. [Video 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2I84DfvMBn2PfDCpMtBE0b5UnyhW6-A/view)

And here is the video of what shows up on me & other computer I tried. [Video 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Imkm53qe-iLzg6VOtL-v1eMNh7Qa0Ghq/view)

Anyone knows the cause of this and how to fix it? is it other plugin cause or something?
The website is here so maybe you can check too please. [Website](http://sanukiudonkotobuki.com/)

Thank you very much

Comment: I've got same problem, have you solved yours?

Answer (score 2):

The website is loading better ( https://www.loom.com/share/38a0581e47264ad698793b5ab116282a ) than your client but still losing images. As I checked its widget-carousel.min.css this resources has been blocked by your site http://sanukiudonkotobuki.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/css/widget-carousel.min.css

this only reason I can see at my end causing the issue after fixing this just clear cache at your server level & clear cache on your client machine by ctrl+shift+r.